# Why does DStream.foreachRDD fail with java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-graphx

I need to build a graph with GraphX based on the processed data from Kafka. However, it seems that `sc.parallelize()` raises the error `java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext`

```
......
val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
  ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)
val lines = messages.map(_._2)

lines.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  rdd.foreachPartition(partition => {
    ......
    // Build a graph
    val vertRDD = sc.parallelize(vertices)
    val edgeRDD = sc.parallelize(edge)
    val graph = Graph(vertRDD, edgeRDD, defaultUser)
    }
  })
})
```

In what way should I solve the problem?

Comment: you are trying to store your `RDD`s inside of an `RDD`
that is impossible - all `RDD`s must be on the driver can you give a more complete code sample?

Comment: You can't create an RDD inside of an RDD. This has been asked so many times on this site.

Comment: Thanks. I have moved `sc.parallelize()` related to outside the `foreachRDD` operation and solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[foreachRDD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream@foreachRDD(foreachFunc:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T]=%3EUnit):Unit) operator in Spark Streaming runs processing RDDs every batch interval on the driver that you then use (through its `RDD`) to write a code that eventually turns itself into Spark jobs.

> **foreachRDD(foreachFunc: (RDD[T]) ⇒ Unit): Unit** Apply a function to each RDD in this DStream. This is an output operator, so 'this' DStream will be registered as an output stream and therefore materialized.

[RDD.foreachPartition](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@foreachPartition(f:Iterator[T]=%3EUnit):Unit) is an action that will only happen on executors.

> **foreachPartition(f: (Iterator[T]) ⇒ Unit): Unit** Applies a function `f` to each partition of this RDD.

Before a task is available for execution on executors it has to be serialized and because `SparkContext` is not serializable, hence the exception. That's how Spark makes sure that `SparkContext` (as `sc`) can never show up due to design decisions in Spark. That would not make sense anyway as the entire scheduling infrastructure is on the driver.

`SparkContext` and `RDD` are only available on the driver. They are simply a way to describe your distributed computations that will eventually get "translated" to tasks that run on Spark executors.

That's why you see the error message:

> java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext

BTW, I answered a similar question today (see [Can SparkContext.textFile be used with a custom receiver?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44769780/1305344)) so it looks like today is a SparkContext day :)